# CPU spec sais 3 ghz while pc shows 2.5 ghz

Tags: cpu

I bought a pc with Intel® Core™ i7-3517U Processor which has Max Turbo Frequency 3 GHz.

my pc was damage and I sent it to a repair lab, they sent it back, but now my pc shows that it has Intel® Core™ i7-3537U Processor which suppose to have Max Turbo Frequency 3.1 GHz.

but my pc shows that it has only 2.49 ghz...

I called the repair lab, and they say that "in order to save battery the pc uses only 2.5 ghz but under load it can reach up to 3 ghz"

I suspect that they are lying to me, can anyone give me some input about this issue?

Comment: Why do you think they call it a "max" frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel i-series processors have a technology they call TurboBoost that dynamically scales the processor speed. If you look at your processor information [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/72054/) it shows its clock speed and max turbo frequency.

Your results fall in the correct range for this processor.

Answer (score 0):

They're correct. This is called [EIST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) or SpeedStep. Put some load on the machine and watch the frequency go up.